# ANTLR: token not expected

Tags: antlr

I have the following grammar:

```
query
: IDENT 'x' NOT
;

WS : (' '| '\t'| EOL)+ { $channel=HIDDEN; };

NOT : ('N'|'n')('O'|'o')('T'|'t');

fragment
EOL : '\n' | '\r';    

fragment
DIGIT : '0'..'9';

fragment LETTER :   ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ;
IDENT : LETTER ( LETTER | DIGIT)*;
```

What i want is to accept any String in front of 'x', but if i use the string "not" at the position of IDENT, it is not accepted. But also "not 'x' not" schould be ok, as well as "foo x not".

Is there an easy way to fix it?

thanks

Comment: That's what a keyword means. To do what you want, you need to add some predicate or semantic rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this, if you just want an easy fix:

```
query
: ( IDENT | NOT ) 'x' NOT
;
```